# Issue with youtub data api, search endpoint, type parameter

Tags: youtube-api

im using this search api URL in my scripts:

[https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&order=date&q=[YOUR_QUERY_STRING]&type=video&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]](https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&order=date&q=%5BYOUR_QUERY_STRING%5D&type=video&key=%5BYOUR_API_KEY%5D)

pretty simple, and it has always worked until a week ago i think. What stopped working is that it returns playlists along with videos even though im clearly specifying the "type" parameter as "video" so it should only return videos.

You can see this happening on googles own dev site:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

it says for type:

```
string
The type parameter restricts a search query to only 
retrieve a particular type of resource. 
The value is a comma-separated list of resource types. 
The default value is video,channel,playlist.

Acceptable values are:
channel
playlist
video
```

So on that page they have the API explorer "try this method" thing , so i use it...

```
part = snippet
maxResults = 25
order = date
q = my search string
type = video
credentials = "api key", not oauth
```

Hit execute / show code and boom i get results but again, it has playlists in the results....
frustrating! any help would be appreciated!
Please and thank you

Comment: Please provide a search string involving the issue.

Comment: the string im using is: chomsky 


im using this search api URL in my scripts:

https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&order=date&q=chomsky&type=video&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]

Comment: I confirm the issue, you just found one of the many YouTube Data API v3 issues.

Comment: As far as I know you just limited the results to contain exactly `22chomsky`, so it absolutely doesn't mean that it solves the issue for any query, even double quoted.

Comment: Benjamin i dont understand why you say that? it seems to work for me when i do %22 as in:
`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&order=date&q=%22chomsky%22&type=video&key=[UR_API_KEY]
`
none of my result contain 22chomsky

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. @Benjamin-Loison inspired me. After you confirmed it, I tried another search string and it worked properly, so then I tried wrapping the search string in double quotes—e.g., `"chomsky"`, or URL encoded as `%22chomsky%22`—and it worked.

UPDATE: I changed my function to include this:

```cs
$encodedSearch = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("`"$search`"")
```

This will encode the quotes for me—and perhaps be more reliable than putting `%22` around the query string.